# How do I know the number of arguments of a function?

Tags: r

How can we know how many arguments a function take?

For instance, for a given function `f`, I'd like to do:

```
if (arg_number(f) == 0)
  f()
else if (arg_number(f) == 1)
  f(FALSE)
```

Comment: See `?formals` perhaps.

Comment: Yes, `length(formalArgs(f))` seems to do the job, thank you. You can post it as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`nargs()`: will check the number of arguments from within the function
[The Number of Arguments to a Function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/nargs.html)

**Edit:**
`formals` will give [access to the arguments of the function](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/formals.html)

```
> f <- function(x, y, z) x + y + z
> formals(f)
> $x
> $y
> $z
```

**Update:** (from @Spacedman)
To know the number of arguments,

```
> length(formals(f))
> [1] 3
```

Also,

```
> length(formalArgs(f))
> [1] 3
```

Comment: No, I won't be in the body of the function I want to examine. `nargs` is to get the number of arguments in the current function

Comment: `length(formals(f))` is slightly better - `formalArgs(f)` is defined as `names(formals(f))`

Comment: "..." counts as one, e.g.: `f <- function(x, y, z, ...) x + y + z; length(formals(f)) #[1] 4`

Comment: @zx8754 Does, `"..." ` pass as a formal argument to the function?